# Angular stateParams without url

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I want to navigate from one url `/projects` to url `/projects/{name}` , but I need to resolve resource by `$stateParams.id`. How can I do it?

Now I have something like this:

```
$stateProvider.state('project.detail', {
...
url: '/projekt/{name}/{id}',
...
resolve: {
            project: ['$stateParams', 'ProjectService', function($stateParams, ProjectService) {
                return ProjectService.get({id : $stateParams.id}).$promise;
            }]
        }
...;
```

But when I remove {id} from the url: '...', it does not work.

My front end navigation is :

`ui-sref="project.detail({name: project.name, id: project.id})"`

And I do not want to have url ...*/projects/hyperloop/5462*

but only ...*/projects/hyperloop*

Thank you!

Comment: Just to make things clear, event though you want to go to `/projects/name`, you still want to get the `id` somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use parameters without specifying them in state URLs. You can specify them in `params` property in state config:

```
$stateProvider.state('project.detail', {
    ...
    url: '/projekt/{name}',
    params: {
      id: null
    },
    resolve: {
            project: ['$stateParams', 'ProjectService', function($stateParams, ProjectService) {
                return ProjectService.get({id : $stateParams.id}).$promise;
            }]
     }
    ...
})
```

Please check [ui-router docs](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing#using-parameters-without-specifying-them-in-state-urls) for more details

Comment: I thought that setting id to null will overwrite my value from view, but it does not. Thank you!